# Eclipse search result in specific method

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, search

In Eclipse `File Search` you have the possibility to search for "containing text" and filter the result with "Filename patterns". For example if you search for `setValue(int x)` with filename pattern "My*.java" you will find the `setValue(int x)` method in a File named `MyGame.java`, but not in a file named `YourGame.java`. Now i need a way to filter the search to only show results in a specific method. For example if i have 10 classes which override a `init()` method and a `reset()` method of the same superclass. Inside the `init()` and the `reset()` the `setValue(int x)` gets called. Now i want to search for all occurences of `setValue(int x)`, but only inside the `init()` methods. Is there a way to do this? With regular expression maybe or does Eclipse have such a method?
Thanks

Comment: Some what related to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577308/eclipse-file-search-regular-expression-for-group-unions-and-negation). You may get some clue from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a more or less working expression:

```
(?s)methodname.*(?-s)set.*parma1, param2
```

Let me explain:

- The "." (DOT) stands for 1 character except "\n" (Newline)
- The "*" (asterisk) means, that the character before it can occure 0-n times, so `n*` matches "nnn", "n" and also "". In combination with "." (DOT) it matches 0-n occurences of any character, except "\n"
- The (?s) modifies the function of "." (DOT), so that it accepts also "\n"
- The (?-s) turns (?s) off, so that the "." (DOT) does not accept "\n" anymore.

So this expression searches for "methodname", followed by 0-n characters (also "\n"), followed by "set", followed by 0-n characters (without "\n"), followed by "param1, param2".
It is possible, that it finds a methodcall after, but outside the "methodname" method, but i don't think you can controll this.
Hope it helps