# Exclude regular expression in file search

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

I would like to search in my eclipse project all files where the expression "BLABLA" isn't in those files.

Examples:

```
File1 : text + blabla
File2 : text without blabla
File3 : text without blabla
File4 : text + blabla
```

I would like to return File 2 and 3.

Thx a lot

Comment: What does `^(?s)(?!.*blabla)` return you? (Or `\A(?s)(?!.*blabla)`). And i assume `blabla` doesn't contain any regex special character?

Comment: Thx for your response. But it return me nothing.
Blabla is just a basic word without any spaces

Comment: @Robin, Please post that as an answer and expand a bit to resolve this question. Thank you.

Comment: @sshashank124: I would have if it were working but I'm not actually sure negative look ahead are supported in eclipse, hence the comment answer. Maxxy: you are using eclipse default search, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group negation for this. Use `(?s)\A(?!.*?blabla).?`.  Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577308/eclipse-file-search-dialog-regular-expression-for-group-unions-and-negation) for more details. Check point no 4 in the question.

Comment: Thx your very much, this is perfect. So nice to know that feature :).